# What's wrong with this sql update statement?

Tags: mysql, powershell

I'm trying to run this in powershell and it gives me an error:

```
$sql.CommandText = "UPDATE signups set offer='$($fileContents[$line.ReadCount+3])' WHERE email='$line' IF @@ROWCOUNT=0 INSERT INTO signups (email,date,offer) VALUES ('"+$line+"','"+$datefin+"','"+$($fileContents[$line.ReadCount+3])+"');"
```

Exception calling "ExecuteNonQuery" with "0" argument(s): "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use 
near 'IF @@ROWCOUNT=0 INSERT INTO signups (email,date,offer) VALUES ('morenonancy50@ya' at line 1"

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your SQL command there is an extra '

This is the last portion your code look right after the ) and you will see the extra '

```
VALUES ('"+$line+"','"+$datefin+"','"+$($fileContents[$line.ReadCount+3])+"')';"
```

So try this instead without the extra '

```
VALUES ('"+$line+"','"+$datefin+"','"+$($fileContents[$line.ReadCount+3])+"');"
```

I would just put it into a comment, but I don't have the rep for that. :)

Comment: Yes that was a problem, but I removed the extra ' and it's giving me the same error. It doesn't seem to like the IF @@ROWCOUNT=0

Comment: Maybe it's the $sql.ExecuteNonQuery() that's causing the problem?